# what kind of time format is this one

Tags: timestamp

I came cross and string of timestamp, not quite sure what kind of format is it:

```
2011-04-20T17:04:55.678+00:00
```

also  i need to specify PST time in the same format, how can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ISO 8601. If you are using Wordpress you can convert it using

```
<?php iso8601_to_datetime( $date_string, $timezone ) ?>
```

where $date_string is your ISO time.

If you are not, use `strtotime($var)`

Answer (score 0):

[ISO_8601](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (or a variant therof)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).